# Distance to a curve achieved along a normal

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $\rho:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^k$ $(k\geq 2)$ defining function of a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. That is:

1. $\Omega = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: \rho(x) < 0\}$
2. $\overline{\Omega}^{\,c} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: \rho(x) > 0\}$
3. $\nabla\rho(x) \neq 0 \ \forall \ x \in\partial\Omega$

My question is, given a point $x$ on $\partial\Omega$ (i.e. $\rho(x)= 0$), is there a point $y$ on the normal $\nu_x$ to $\partial\Omega$ at $x$ such that for all $z$ between $x$ and $y$ on $\nu_x$, $\|x - z\|={\rm dist}(z,\partial\Omega)$?

It seems to me that if we can guarantee a possibly scaled down version of the circle of curvature at $x$ which intersects $\partial\Omega$ only at $x$ then we are done.

Comment: Your "circle of curvature" suggestion is definitely a good track - try to prove the "exterior sphere condition", i.e. the existence of a ball $B$ such that $\bar B \cap \bar \Omega = \{x\}.$ You should be able to do this fairly easily by writing $\partial \Omega$ locally as a graph.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thanks very much for the suggestion. I was also hoping another simple approach could be made to work, viz., in a small enough neighbourhood of x, the boundary will be so nearly flat that some simple mean value type estimates should settle the issue.